Why is there a small difference between gradients calculated using torch autograd vs functorch?
I am using this linked solution from a previous question to compute gradients more efficiently than a manual loop.
I notice that there is some small difference in the gradients calculated using the two methods (i.e. torch.abs(grads_torch - grads_func).sum() returns ~1e-05). What might explain this difference? Is one solution more correct than the other?
MWE
import torch
from torchvision import datasets, transforms
import torch.nn as nn

###### SETUP ######

class MLP(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, output_size):
        super(MLP, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(input_size, hidden_size)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(hidden_size, output_size)
        
    def forward(self, x):
        h = self.fc1(x)
        pred = self.fc2(self.relu(h))
        return pred
    
train_dataset = datasets.MNIST(root='./data', train=True, download=True, 
                            transform=transforms.Compose(
                                [transforms.ToTensor(),
                                    transforms.Normalize((0.5,), (0.5,))
        ]))

train_dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=2, shuffle=False)

X, y = next(iter(train_dataloader))  # take a random batch of data

net = MLP(28*28, 20, 10)  # define a network


###### CALCULATE GRADIENTS WITH TORCH AUTOGRAD GRAD ######
def calculate_gradients(model, X):
    # Create a tensor to hold the gradients
    gradients = torch.zeros(X.shape[0], 10, sum(p.numel() for p in model.parameters()))

    # Calculate the gradients for each input and target dimension
    for i in range(X.shape[0]):
        for j in range(10):
            model.zero_grad()
            output = model(X[i])
            # Calculate the gradients
            grads = torch.autograd.grad(output[j], model.parameters())
            # Flatten the gradients and store them
            gradients[i, j, :] = torch.cat([g.view(-1) for g in grads])
            
    return gradients

grads_torch = calculate_gradients(net, X.view(X.shape[0], -1))

###### NOW CALCULATE THE SAME GRADIENTS WITH FUNCTORCH ######
# extract the parameters and buffers for a functional call
params = {k: v.detach() for k, v in net.named_parameters()}
buffers = {k: v.detach() for k, v in net.named_buffers()}

def one_sample(sample):
    # this will calculate the gradients for a single sample
    # we want the gradients for each output wrt to the parameters
    # this is the same as the jacobian of the network wrt the parameters

    # define a function that takes the as input returns the output of the network
    call = lambda x: torch.func.functional_call(net, (x, buffers), sample)
    
    # calculate the jacobian of the network wrt the parameters
    J = torch.func.jacrev(call)(params)
    
    # J is a dictionary with keys the names of the parameters and values the gradients
    # we want a tensor
    grads = torch.cat([v.flatten(1) for v in J.values()],-1) 
    return grads

# no we can use vmap to calculate the gradients for all samples at once
grads_func = torch.vmap(one_sample)(X.flatten(1))

print(torch.allclose(grads_torch, grads_func))  # returns True
print(torch.abs(grads_torch - grads_func).sum())  # returns tensor(1.4454e-05)


Without knowing the actual reason, also suspect fixed bitsize floating point rounding when two different methods yield "almost the same" results (and note that there's no such thing as 10e-06 because of how scientific notation works. That has to be 1e-5 to be "properly" written).

@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I was thinking it might be related to floating point representation but (1) I would like to know for sure if and where this is happening and (2) I also ran a different experiment with a sin function where I know the ground truth gradients and in that case both methods recover the correct solution exactly. Note that small difference in gradients can accumulate over updates meaning that this small difference can actually be meaningful.
